# Parts with the maximum number of each integer

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $n$ be a positive integer. Some integers between $1$ and $n$ (inclusive) are written on a line, where the same integer can appear multiple times. Is it true that we can always divide the line into $n$ parts and assign to each part a label between $1$ and $n$ (inclusive), where each label is used exactly once, so that for any $1\leq i\leq n$, the part labeled $i$ contains at least as many copies of the integer $i$ as any other part?

If $n=1$ then this is trivially true, because we only write $1$s and we do not need to divide the line at all.

If $n=2$ it is also true: Move from the left of the line until at least half of all the $1$s or half of all the $2$s are reached, then stop and divide the line. Say we have reached at least half of all the $1$s. Then label the left part with $1$ and the right part with $2$.

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2163370/dividing-triples-of-nonnegative-real-numbers).

Comment: This seems vaguely related to a necklace problem which was solved with Borsuk Ulam. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1121539/26369

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This follows from David Gale's generalization of Knaster–Kuratowski–Mazurkiewicz lemma. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski%E2%80%93Mazurkiewicz_lemma#Permutations) for the formulation of the generalization and the relevant terminology.

To prove the theorem, we first make the problem continuous:

> For each $i=0, \dots, L-1$, the unit (open) interval $(i, i+1)$ has color $j$ for some $j \in [n]$. Is it true that we can always divide the interval $[0, L]$ into $n$ disjoint (open) intervals $I_1, \dots, I_n$ (from left to right) of length $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ and find a permutation $\pi\in S_n$ so that for any $i\in[n]$, the total length of color $\pi(i)$ in interval $I_i$ is at least as much as in any other interval?

Once we prove the continuous version, we can "round" each interval in the following way. If the left end point $a$ of interval $I_i$ is colored $\pi(i)$, we round $a$ to $\lfloor a\rfloor$. Similarly, if the right end point $b$ of interval $I_{i}$ is colored by $\pi(i)$, we round $b$ to $\lceil b\rceil$. If there are end points not rounded yet, we round them arbitrarily. One can show that the resulting partition gives a solution to the discrete version.

Finally, we prove the continuous version. Consider the $(n-1)$-simplex $$\Delta := \left\{(x_1, \dots, x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n:x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n = L,x_1, \dots, x_n \ge 0\right\},$$ with vertices $v_i = Le_i$, where $e_1, \dots, e_n$ forms the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

For every $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \Delta$, define the (open) interval $I_i(x) = (x_1+\dots+x_{i-1}, x_1+\dots+x_{i})$ for all $i\in [n]$, and we say $I_i(x)$ is dominant in color $j$ if the total length of color $j$ in interval $I_i(x)$ is at least as much as in the other $I_*(x)$.
For every $i \in [n]$ and $j \in [n]$, let
$$C_i^j := \{x\in\Delta: I_i(x) \text{ is dominant in color }j\}.$$

One can check that for every $j\in[n]$, $C_1^j, \dots, C_n^j$ is a KKM covering. By David Gale's result, there exists a permutation $\pi$ such that $$\bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i^{\pi(i)}\neq \emptyset.$$

In other words, there is $(x_1, \dots, x_n)\in \Delta$ such that $(x_1, \dots, x_n)\in C_{i}^{\pi(i)}$ for all $i\in[n]$, that is, $I_i(x)$ is dominant in color $\pi(i)$.