# Papers on Applied Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, research

I am taking a course on applied algebraic topology and we are tasked with presenting a paper on the subject. We were given https://arxiv.org/search/math to look for potential papers, but I am having trouble finding material that is within the grasp of undergrad. Some topics covered in our course have been

- Homology of simplicial complexes
- Vietoris–Rips complex
- Persistent homology
- Bar codes

If you know any interesting papers on the subject or know other places to look, please let me know!

Comment: A good place to start is Carlsson's classic survey [Persistent Homology and Applied Homotopy Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.00738).

Comment: You could look at directed algebraic topology as well. There are a handful of notable papers on the topic if you look it up.

Comment: Also look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1121338.